Why is my search input hovering, the location where I have put the icons?
I don't know what went wrong but my Search bar is hovering, even though I don't want it to. I just want all the buttons to hover which are down the search button. Please look at it and lemme know what went wrong?
I am trying to build a side navigation panel, I have started coding after a lot of time and trying to refresh everything. I just can't figure ut this one.
Here's my HTML -
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- Boxicons CSS -->

    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <title>Dashboard - Sidebar Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="sidebar">
      <header>
        <div class="image-text">
          <span class="image">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
          </span>

          <div class="text header-text">
            <span class="name">Google</span>
            <span class="proession">Internet Services Company</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i class="bx bx-chevron-right toggle"></i>
      </header>

      <div class="menu-bar">
        <div class="menu">
          <li class="search-box">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="bx bx-search icon"></i>
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            </a>
          </li>

          <ul class="menu-links">
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bx bx-home-alt icon"></i>
                <span class="text nav-text">Dashboard</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2 icon"></i>
                <span class="text nav-text">Revenue</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bx bx-bell icon"></i>
                <span class="text nav-text">Notification</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bx bx-pie-chart-alt icon"></i>
                <span class="text nav-text">Analytics</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bx bx-heart icon"></i>
                <span class="text nav-text">Likes</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bx bx-wallet icon"></i>
                <span class="text nav-text">Wallet</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-content">
          <li class="">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="bx bx-log-out icon"></i>
              <span class="text nav-text">Logout</span>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="mode">
            <div class="moon-sun">
              <i class="bx bx-moon icon moon"></i>
              <i class="bx bx-sun icon sun"></i>
            </div>

            <span class="mode-text text"> Dark Mode </span>

            <div class='toggle-switch'>
                <span class='switch'>
                    
                </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Here's the CSS -
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  /* ===== Colors ====*/

  --body-color: #e4e9f7;
  --sidebar-color: #fff;
  --primary-color: #695cfe;
  --primary-color-light: #f6f5ff;
  --toggle-color: #ddd;
  --text-color: #707070;

  /* =====Transition===== */

  --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
  --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
  --tran-04: all 0.4s ease;
  --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: var(--body-color);
}

/* ====== Sidebar ====== */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: var(--sidebar-color);
}

/* ====== Reusable CSS ====== */

.sidebar .text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.sidebar .image {
  min-width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar li {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar li .icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar li .icon,
.sidebar li .text {
  color: var(--text-color);
  transform: var(--tran-02);
}

.sidebar header {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .image-text img {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.sidebar header .image-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .image-text .header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-text .name {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.header-text .profession {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.sidebar header .toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--sidebar-color);
  font-size: 22px;
}

.sidebar .search-box {
  background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
}

.search-box input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
}

.sidebar li a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transform: var(--tran-04);
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}



.sidebar li a:hover .icon,
 .sidebar li a:hover .text {
    color: var(--sidebar-color);
}

.sidebar .menu-bar {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.menu-bar .mode {
background: var(--primary-color-light);
}


.menu-bar .mode .moon-sun {
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.menu-bar .mode .i {
  position: absolute
}

.menu-bar .mode i.sun {
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-bar .mode .toggle-switch {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
       cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-switch .switch {
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: var(--toggle-color);
}

.switch::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    
}


The searchbar is hovering because you have it's components inside an <a></a> tag, like other buttons, where you are applying the hovering on all of the a elements inside the <li></li>
To fix it, just change the inner <a> element inside the search-box class to be
<li class="search-box">
   <div>
      <i class="bx bx-search icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
   </div>
</li>

Then update your css to be applied on that new div as well.
.sidebar li a, .sidebar li div{
   /* Same as previous styles, just made applied it on the div above for the searchbar */
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-radius: 6px;
   transform: var(--tran-04);
}

